# D6: a homepage with only blocks?

Tags: drupal

the homepage of the design im currently converting in to a drupal site has 6 equally sized blocks of content (im not using the drupal term "blocks" here), showing a tagcloud, a list of the last 5 published titles, a delicious tagcloud, a "what is this site about" area etc.

my question is: is it possible / acceptable / standard practise to output only "blocks" and no "page" on the homepage, using Views? id assume a "page" would be the "main content area" of the homepage but since there isnt such an area im thinking of going just with blocks.

how does that sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module may do what you are looking for here. Panels 3 is just out and looks like it can do just what you want.

Comment: that does sound good. it just occured to me that all "pages" need a path, so by definition it wouldnt be right to have a "page on the homepage" ...

Answer (score 0):

Using two definitions for 'blocks' doesn't help you here. Page content, a view for instance, or a "what's the site about page" can still be page content if it's small and fits into a grid.

Answer (score 0):

You have a choice of either using the panels module or of defining your own home page template by creating a page-front.tpl.php within your theme.  Within the page-front.tpl.php you could specify in the markup the regions you want, defined in your .info theme file.  In this case your page-front.tpl.php would contain 6 regions and you could simply then assign blocks to those regions within the adminstration area of Drupal.

Comment: sounds good but i took the Panel route and that seems to work great :)